# Using Map function with Lambda: TypeError: () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, typeerror, positional-argument

**System:** WIN10

**IDE:** MS VSCode

**Language:** Python version 3.7.3

**Library:** pandas version 1.0.1

**Data source:** base data supplied below

**Dataset:** base data supplied below

I am having an issue for some reason when trying to use the "map" function to map A converter function (I built using lambda) to iterate across a list of sample temperatures. The sample code is supplied below and it keeps throwing the following error: TypeError: () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

**Steps were taken:**

1. tested independent pieces of the code to ensure the list of tuples in temps made since
2. searched online for the error code and could not find anything

**Code:**

```
temps = [('Berlin', 29), ('Cairo', 36), ('Buenos Aires', 19), ('Los Angeles', 26), ('Tokyo', 27), ('New York', 28), ('London', 22), ('Beijing', 32)]

c_to_f = lambda: (data[0], (9/5)*data[1] + 32)

list(map(c_to_f, temps))
```

**error**

```
TypeError: () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function will pass each element of `temps` as an argument to `c_to_f`.

Change your `c_to_f` definition so it takes an argument:

```
def c_to_f(data):
    return data[0], (9/5)*data[1] + 32
```

or just do:

```
list(map(lambda data: (data[0], (9/5)*data[1] + 32), temps))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using lambda, someone else was able to use the lambda map marriage the way I have it above and it worked for them. I am trying to find out if there is something I did wrong maybe?

Comment: Yes, but it's considered bad style to name a lambda function.  The whole point of a lambda expression is for cases where you just need to pipe something together and don't need to name a function for it; if you need to name a function, just use `def`.  :)  Will also give an example with lambda.

Comment: Thank you Samwise!